# 2d array challenge access elements

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

Attempting the hackerRank Q from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/2d-array

```
 static void Main(String[] args)
            {
                int[][] arr = new int[6][];
                for (int arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++)
                {
                    string[] arr_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                    arr[arr_i] = Array.ConvertAll(arr_temp, Int32.Parse);
                }
                int[] sum = new int[6];
                List<int> n = new List<int>();

                for (int i = 0; i + 2 < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j + 2 < arr.GetLength(0); j++)
                    {
                        sum[j] = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j + 1] + arr[i][j + 2] +
                                         arr[i + 1][j + 1] +
                            arr[i + 2][j] + arr[i + 2][j + 1] + arr[i + 2][j + 2];
                        n.Add(sum[j]);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(n.Max());
            }
        }
    }
```

If I run this program and enter the following as contents of 'arr'
111111
222222
333333
444444
555555
666666

```
Here I am trying to add 1 + 1 + 1 
                          + 2 +
                        3 + 3 + 3



  using sum[j] = arr[i][j] + arr[i][j + 1] + arr[i][j + 2] +
                                     arr[i + 1][j + 1] +
                        arr[i + 2][j] + arr[i + 2][j + 1] + arr[i + 2][j + 2];

but arr[i][j] returns 111111

how can I access 1? is this the right answer to the question on hackerrank?
```

Comment: hakkerranck  has it 's set of tests try it on the site

Comment: Look carefully at how you initialise the array - try printing it out to see if it gives the expected values.

Comment: What's your question? I use exactly the same code you posted and got accepted. And I think you missed the space in your sample input? That's not a valid input at all

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code helps you

```
public class Solution {
private static final int _MAX = 6; // size of matrix
private static final int _OFFSET = 2; // hourglass width
private static int matrix[][] = new int[_MAX][_MAX];
private static int maxHourglass = -63; // initialize to lowest possible sum (-9 x 7)

/** Given a starting index for an hourglass, sets maxHourglass
*   @param i row 
*   @param j column 
**/
private static void hourglass(int i, int j){
    int tmp = 0; // current hourglass sum

    // sum top 3 and bottom 3 elements
    for(int k = j; k <= j + _OFFSET; k++){
        tmp += matrix[i][k]; 
        tmp += matrix[i + _OFFSET][k]; 
    }
    // sum middle element
    tmp += matrix[i + 1][j + 1]; 

    if(maxHourglass < tmp){
        maxHourglass = tmp;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // read inputs
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    for(int i=0; i < _MAX; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < _MAX; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
    scan.close();

    // find maximum hourglass
    for(int i=0; i < _MAX - _OFFSET; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < _MAX - _OFFSET; j++){
            hourglass(i, j);
        }
    }

    // print maximum hourglass
    System.out.println(maxHourglass);
}
```

}